# Drupal 7 unable to get referenced node in view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a node called "Student" I have another node called "Personal details".
I have made relations between them using entity reference module.

Now I am creating a view to get details of all students. I created a view of students and selected Content "Personal details" on fileds of the view. But I am only getting the id of the "Personal details".

I am struging to get the name and other fields of personal details node.

I used Relationships-> Entity Reference: Personal details and added content entityreference in fields but it is not displaying aything when i printing the view using get_view API.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think this should work. Try to create a view for all types.
2. Select the fields that you want to display (the fields from students and personal info ). Chose to display both Id's from Student node and from the Personal info node, but make 1 of them invisible, to not be shown. ( you will understand why in step 4 ).
3. Add a filter, the Global: Fields comparison.
4. Select the two fields that have to be equal (the ID's).